# Is there a way to not pass an argument in Common-Lisp instead of passing "NIL"?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm calling functions according to user input, but some have two parameters and others just one. Instead of using &optional parameter on every function (and never using it), is there a way to simply not pass an argument when it's value is "NIL"?

This is for an interactive fiction game, in which the user type some commands and these are converted into function calls.

```
(defun inputs (state)
    (format *query-io* "> ")
    (force-output *query-io*)
    (let* ((entry (cl-ppcre:split "\\s+" (string-downcase (read-line *query-io*))))
      (function (car entry))
      (args (cdr entry)))
      (if (valid-call function)
      (funcall (symbol-function (read-from-string function))
           state
           args)
      (progn
        (format *query-io* "Sorry, I don't know the command '~a'~%~%" function)
        (inputs state)))))
```

If the user input is "equip sword", I need to call the function "equip" passing the '("Sword") as argument, but if the user input is "status", I need to call the function "status" without passing the 'args', instead of passing them as "NIL"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm)
instead of [`funcall`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm),
[`find-symbol`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_find_s.htm) instead of
[`read-from-string`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_fro.htm) (this is actually important for [security reasons](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhf.htm)!)
and [`destructuring-bind`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_destru.htm)
instead of [`let*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm):

```
(defun inputs (state)
  (format *query-io* "> ")
  (force-output *query-io*)
  (destructuring-bind (command &rest args)
      (cl-ppcre:split "\\s+" (string-downcase (read-line *query-io*)))
    (if (valid-call command)
        (apply (find-symbol command) state args)
        (progn
          (format *query-io* "Sorry, I don't know the command '~a'~%~%" command)
          (inputs state)))))
```

Using `apply` lets your commands accept an arbitrary number of arguments instead of one.

In fact, your `valid-call` should probably return the function to be called:

```
(let ((f (valid-call function)))
  (if f
      (apply f state args)
      ...)
```

Comment: The find-symbol application didn't worked well. I have separated the code in two packages: #:game and #:commands, and created a game.asd file, in which I defined the game system. If I try to apply the function using the find-symbol (instead of read-from-string), an error appears, informing that the function COMMANDS::|function| is undefined, even if the function is defined and exported in the #:commands package.

Comment: Try `(find-symbol (string-upcase command) '#:commands)` or intern commands in the correct case. Remember, CL is case-sensitive while the _default_ reader is  case-converting.

Comment: Actually, the `find-symbol` returned `COMMANDS:|function|
:EXTERNAL`, the error appear when tried to `apply` this function. I'm recently learning about packages and systems, maybe the problem is something in the definitions. Here are the codes for the three definitions:

Comment: You should make sure that your packages (game and commands) do not use ther standard packages and do not inherit from them.

Comment: I'm trying since yesterday and still not found a solution.The code on my game.asd file is:
`(asdf:defsystem "game"
  :depends-on (#:cl-ppcre)
  :components ((:file "game")
        (:file "commands")))`
The commands.lisp file starts with:
`(defpackage :commands
  (:use :cl)
  (:export "end" "sheet" "status" "save" "restore" "reload" "location" "inventory" "equipped"))`
And the game.lisp file starts with:
`(defpackage :game
  (:use :cl :cl-ppcre))`
Do I need to use  the `in-package` function? 
The commands.lisp calls some functions from the game.lisp, and the game calls the commands

Comment: This is getting too hairy for comments. You should ask a separate question (and link it from this comment thread).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a simple `LOOP` instead of a recursive call:

```
(defun inputs (state)
  (loop
   (format *query-io* "> ")
   (force-output *query-io*)
   (let* ((entry (cl-ppcre:split "\\s+" (string-downcase (read-line *query-io*))))
          (function (car entry))
          (args     (cdr entry)))
     (when (valid-call function)
       (apply (symbol-function (find-symbol function))
              state
              args)
       (return))
     (format *query-io* "Sorry, I don't know the command '~a'~%~%" function))))
```

Comment: Your function does not return the value of `apply`.