# Problem with package communication Common-Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have two packages defined: `game` (file `game.lisp`) and `commands` (file `commands.lisp`), loaded by a `game.asd` file. I'm having trouble in calling commands functions (that have been exported), using the `(symbol-function (find-symbol "test-function" 'commands))`, which returns that the function is undefined, even if the `(find-symbol "test-function" 'commands)` returned that the function is external, and belongs to the `commands` package.

The code on the `game.asd` file is:

```
(asdf:defsystem "game"
  :depends-on (#:cl-ppcre)
  :components ((:file "game")
               (:file "commands")))
```

The `game.lisp` starts with:

```
(defpackage :game
  (:use :cl :cl-ppcre))
```

The `commands.lisp` starts with:

```
(defpackage :commands
  (:use :cl)
  (:export "test-function"))
```

Do I need to use the `in-package` function?
From the `game.lisp` I call the commands stored in the `commands.lisp` file, and some of these calls some functions on the `game.lisp`, for example:

```
(defun test-function ()
  (progn
    (format *query-io* "Worked!~%")
    (start)))
```

The `test-function` is located on the commands package, but calls the `start` function, which belongs to the `game.lisp`.

I expect the calling of the `test-function` function, when I call `(symbol-function (find-symbol "test-function" 'commands))`.

Comment: you can `:use ... :commands` package in `:game` to make exported functions "local": `(defpackage :game (:use :cl :cl-ppcre :commands))`.

Comment: I switched the initialization order on the game.asd (otherwise, the system was returning that the commands package was not found) and added the `commands` package into the `use` of the `game` package definition, but the error still appears (function is undefined)

Comment: Symbols are uppercase in Common Lisp by default.  Use "TEST-FUNCTION" as a symbol name string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Summary

My main recommendation is that you should have *separate* packages that contain user commands and that contain your Lisp code.

You do *not* have to create a separate package for each Lisp file you have.

## Details

You do need the [`in-package`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_in_pkg.htm)
*macro* (it is not a *function*!) to ensure that your code resides in the
correct package, because
[`defpackage`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpkg.htm) merely *creates*
the package, it does *not* change
[`*package*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pkg.htm).

Thus I suggest the following:

### Files

#### `game.asd`

```
(asdf:defsystem "game"
  :depends-on (#:cl-ppcre)
  :components ((:file "package")
               (:file "game" :depends-on ("package"))
               (:file "commands" :depends-on ("package"))))
```

#### `package.lisp`

```
(defpackage :game
  (:use :cl :cl-ppcre))
```

#### `game.lisp`

```
(in-package #:game)

...
```

#### `commands.lisp`

```
(in-package #:game)

...

(defconstant *commands-package* (make-package '#:commands :use nil))
```

and then use [`intern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_intern.htm) to add
commands to `*commands-package*` and [`find-symbol`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_find_s.htm) to find them.

```
(defun test-command ()
  (format t "test-command~%")
  (start))
(intern 'test-command *commands-package*)
```

You could also define your own macro for that:

```
(defmacro defcommand (name arglist &body body)
  `(progn
     (intern (symbol-name ',name) *commands-package*)
     (defun ,name ,arglist ,@body)))

(defcommand test-command ()
  (format t "test-command~%")
  (start))
```

### Nitpicks

- Do not wrap the function body in an explicit
  [`progn`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_progn.htm), because
  [`defun`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm) does that for you.
- [`find-symbol`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_find_s.htm) finds a
  [`symbol`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_symbol.htm), not a
  [`function`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_fn.htm).
- Do not forget to [`string-upcase`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_stg_up.htm) the argument to [`find-symbol`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_find_s.htm).

Comment: About the macro, the error `The value
  TEST-COMMAND
is not of type
  STRING
when binding SB-IMPL::NAME` is appearing when trying to load and compile the `commands.lisp`.
Just to make sure, in the REPL I need to load and compile the game.asd file, call `(asdf:load-system 'game)` and change the package to `:game`?
Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: It does not matter whether you interact with your code in CL-USER package or in GAME package, it is only a question of personal convenience.

Comment: Uiop (part of ASDF) has `uiop:standard-case-symbol-name`, which at least also supports Allegro's “modern” mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you do the `find-symbol` stuff. If you just want to call a function that is defined in another package, you have two options:

- as said in a comment, you can `use` the other package:

```
    (defpackage :game 
      (:use :cl 
            :cl-ppcre 
            :commands))
    (in-package :game)
```

- or call the function with `(commands:test-function)` (with a double colon `::` if the function wasn't exported).

Here is an example definition for a new project: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/getting-started.html#creating-a-new-project

see also tips to deal with packages: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/packages.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the material provided, but doing just this wasn't working. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200901/is-there-a-way-to-not-pass-an-argument-in-common-lisp-instead-of-passing-nil) question I explained why I needed the `find-symbol` (was to call a function from an user input, converted from a string).